# Подскажите совсем небольшие opensource проект на python

Tags: python, opensource

Подскажите совсем небольшие opensource проекты на python, желательно с использованием wxPython. Только не надо предлагать там что-нить из какого-то дистрибутива Linux. Можно даже какие-то недоделанные. Просто немного поковыряться в реальном коде.

Спасибо.

Comment: Думаю ссылку на гитхаб и иже с ним, будет как-то фривольно.

Comment: нет-нет - в самый раз :)

тем более, что щас там прикрутили Ace (Cloud9 поделку) - стало совсем красиво :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно здесь посмотреть: http://python.su/forum/viewforum.php?id=30

Вот к примеру http://python.su/forum/viewtopic.php?id=10584 написана с использованием wxPython

Comment: спасибо большое, много интересных проектов, буду смотреть

Answer (score 0):

Вон вам ссылка. Результаты даже уже рассортированы ))

https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=wxPython